# Question about max function in python when the input is 2 same values

Tags: python

```
daf = [2,2]

if all values in the array are the same

       print ("error")
else

       print(daf.index(max(daf)))
```

I don't know how to write the if statement for the above code since

```
daf = [2,2]

print(daf.index(max(daf)))
```

just returns 0 which is also the first index of the array

Comment: `if len(set(daf)) == 1:`? If the size is always 2, why not just `if daf[0] == daf[1]`? How is your question about `max` function? Your question is how to find if all elements in a list are equal, and if you would google exactly that - you would find your solution

Answer (score 4):

For the if statement, you can use `set` which returns a list of all the unique values. If `len == 1` then there was only one unique value.

```
if len(set(dat)) == 1:
   print('error')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python's `all` function to do this:

```
if all(x == daf[0] for x in daf):
  print("error")
```